# jQuery Toggle Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been a while since I've touched any jQuery, and I was a laughable idiot in my "prime".  I'm hoping to have a footer nav pop out when a certain icon is clicked.  I've tried the js in an external file, and now in my html file just to make sure my code is wrong.  I have jQuery included like so:

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- <script src="js/main.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>
```

part one of the html in question, the image with the id of "add" is what will be clicked to toggle:

```
<section id="side">
        <nav class="sidebar"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></img>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="docs.html"> Providers </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Quality </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
            </ul>
            <img id="add" src="images/phoner.png"></img>
        </nav>
    </side>
```

and here is both what I'd like to popout on click of the aforementioned image, and the jQuery:

```
<footer id="footer">
                          <ul>
                             <li> <h2> Joint Replacements </h2></li>
                             <li> <h2>Sports Medicine </h2></li>
                             <li> <h2>Orthopedic Trauma & Fractures </h2></li>
                          </ul>
                     </footer>

        </section>
        <script>
        $( "#add" ).click(function() {
            $( "#footer" ).toggle( "slow" );
        });
        </script>
```

Thanks to any and all for any input.

Edit- this in my console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (jquery.min.js, line 0)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    global code (mmp.html, line 74)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 0)
```

Comment: You're not closing the `<section>` properly?

Comment: I believe the html is all OK, I just didnt want to include the entire file here

Comment: Works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yaz7ac8v/)** and yea with the html change from `</side>` to `</section>`. Check for any console errors!!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x5y6uLkc/

Comment: For somebody who just posted a question, perhaps you should believe less and question more :)

Comment: Got me on that one @Jack, still can't figure out why this one won't work for me however.

Comment: @Alex since there are multiple fiddles where it is working you may have to try to recreate the issue in the fiddle

Comment: @Alex also whether the elements are created dynamically after the page is loaded... try to put your script in a dom ready handler....

Comment: Doesn't like my jQuery URL? Please see edit

Comment: Just prepend the https://

Comment: @Alex are you loading the test file from your local files system(`file://` in your address) or from a web server(`http://` or `https://`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine in the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmws8wLp/):

```
<nav class="sidebar">
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
      <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
          <li> <a href="docs.html"> Providers </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Quality </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
      </ul>
    <img id="add" src="images/phoner.png" />
</nav>


<footer id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li> <h2> Joint Replacements </h2></li>
        <li> <h2>Sports Medicine </h2></li>
        <li> <h2>Orthopedic Trauma & Fractures </h2></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

JS:

```
 $( "#add" ).click(function() {
     $( "#footer" ).toggle( "slow" );
 });
```

1. Check if jQuery is loaded
2. Check for any console errors
3. Check if your script is being executed

Comment: Thanks man, valuable lesson in the final three steps I had forgotten